# Apache + Passenger starting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

[image]
How to avoid this error? I also used chmod 777 to PassengerAgent directory.

Comment: Couple things could cause that probably...What user / group owns your app directory? Did you install RVM with sudo?

Comment: I tried to give full access to app directory, via chmod -R 777 /var/www/dotanewworld  - the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the /root directory is not accessible. You need to fix permissions there too.